# Change date after add date mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to change date only to `1` after add date, what i must to do ?

This is the code

```
select DATE_FORMAT(Tgl_Lahir, '%e-%m-%Y')
AS Tanggal_Lahir,
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(Tgl_Lahir, INTERVAL '55 - 1' YEAR_MONTH), '%e-%m-%Y')
AS Tanggal_Pensiun
FROM tabel_pegawai
```

This the result
[Result query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrqBQ.png)

So, can i change date only into `1` in `Tanggal_Pensiun` column ?
example :

```
12-01-2000 to 1-01-2000
23-05-1998 to 1-05-1998
```

Thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your question correctly or not.
But, if you need to change only date format, please try the below code.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(Tgl_Lahir, '%e-%m-%Y')
AS Tanggal_Lahir,
DATE_FORMAT(Tgl_Lahir, '01-%m-%Y')
AS Tanggal_Pensiun
FROM tabel_pegawai
```